# JSON is Malformed in Fetch POST request using React Native

Tags: json, react-native

I have a function in a React Native app that is supposed to send data to a server that I'm hosting. This function seems to be throwing errors though every time I press submit and this function is called. The function should be sending a POST request to my webserver and receive information back. It has no problem receiving information but sending is another story... The current code below is giving me an error that says "JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'. But as you can see in my code below I do not even have that symbol present in the 2nd parameter of the fetch function. Occasionally, when I tweak what I have I get an error that also says 'JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF'. I am not sure how exactly this request is I guess 'malformed'. I am pulling it straight from the docs given by Facebook. I have also tried Axiom & XMLHttpRequest and I am still seeing similar JSON errors. Anyone?

```
login = () => {
    // check if the username is being passed off properly...
    //alert(this.state.username);
    fetch('MYURL', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
      })
    })
    .then(function(response){ return response.json(); }) // transforms response into data that is readable for this app...
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .done();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I shoot that post request in Postman I get back header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8". So you don't get json back at all, that's why it doesn't work. I would venture that you have to add the correct application/json header in your backend.

Comment: This was the issue. I see on my server it it sending POST request now. Thank you